# Query by multiple doc_ids in Google App Engine Search API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I want to retrieve a list of documents from a list of doc_ids. Something akin to doing the following in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE id IN (1,2,3,167,91)
```

I see this method in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/indexclass#Index_get), but that only retrieves a single document. For efficiency, I want to do a batch retrieval. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a batch `get` function, but there is an async version (search https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.search.search for `get_async`), so you could do something like (untested pseudo-code):

```
# query for docs ids in advance
futures = []
for id_ in doc_ids:
    futures.append(index.get_async(id_))

# dereference the futures when you need them
ids = [x.get_result() for x in futures]
```